# If some complex numbers lie on the one side of a line which goes through 0, then the sum of them are not 0

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let me describe the problem more specifically.

Suppose that $z_{1},z_{2},\cdots,z_{n}$ are all complex number and they all lie on one side of a straight line passing through $0$. Then $z_{1}+z_{2}+\cdots+z_{n}\neq0$.

I am asked to prove it analytically, even thought it seems quite clear geometrically. So I am thinking that I could use some inequality to prove, but don't have any idea yet..

Thank you very much for any hints or explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:*

- Choose a (nonzero) factor $c$ such that all numbers $w_i = c \cdot z_i$
  lie in the upper half-plane.
- Consider the sum of imaginary parts of the $w_i$.

*Detailed solution:*

A straight line though the origin with “direction” $\varphi$ is 
given by
$$
 L = \{ te^{i\varphi} \mid t \in \Bbb R \}
 = \{ z \in \Bbb C \mid \operatorname{Im}(e^{-i\varphi} z) = 0 \}
$$
If all $z_i$ lie on one side of the line $L$ then either
$$ 
  \operatorname{Im}(e^{-i\varphi} z_i) > 0 \text{ for all }i
$$
or 
$$ 
  \operatorname{Im}(e^{-i\varphi} z_i) < 0 \text{ for all }i
$$
In both cases,
$$
 \operatorname{Im}(e^{-i\varphi} (z_1 + \ldots + z_n)) \ne 0 \, .
$$

Comment: is this possible? I think the value of c has to depend on $z_{i}$, otherwise if if there is a $z_{i}$ lies in the right half-plane, the c which makes every $z_{j}$ from left half-plane go to right half-plane will make that $z_{i}$ go to left half-plane...

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: No, $c$ depends only on the given straight line. It is chosen such this line is rotated onto the imaginary axis.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much... it is really wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to give a characterization of those numbers. Since the lines passes through $0$, let's suppose it forms with the positive $x$ semiaxis and angle $\alpha$, what can you say of the $\arg(z_i)$ for all the points on one side and what for those on the other side?

Comment: they are all lager than the angle $\alpha$?

Comment: But they are smaller than some other angle.

Answer (score 2):

Rotate the plane about the origin so the given line coincides with the imaginary axis.  Then all the points have positive real part or all have negative real part.

Comment: I understand this, but what should I do if the line does not coincide with the imaginary axis? I think my question is related to what Martin R suggested, but I cannot find that constant $c$

Comment: If $\varphi$ is the angle between the real axis and your line, then multiply the plane with $e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi)} $ and the line coincides with the imaginary axis. @JacobsonRadical

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you so much for making it clear. I really want to accept both your answer and Martin R's..